# Mitmproxy url filter

Tags: networking, filter, proxy, server, mitmproxy

I am using mitmproxy on Mac. I want to filter traffic by specifyc URL. The "intercept" function allows me to pause communication whenever filtered url is noticed. My question is - how can I filter traffic without pausing communication? I want it to continue to update without necessity to push "a" or "A".

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions; this probably belongs on [SU]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can press `f` to show only flows that match your criteria.

See https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-filters/ for the full filter syntax.

Comment: Hi Maximilian! Is it possible to use `--ignore-hosts`  or `--view-filter` with multiple domains ?